# How did Korra defeat Unavatu anyway?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

Korra lost raava. That means she is just a regular bender, not even an avatar anymore.

Then a bunch of things start not making sense.

Unalag becomes "big" and want to bring "darkness". I think south park parody this in one of their episode.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecha-Streisand

What's the point? The evilest dictators in the world don't want to be giant and bring darkness. Even Hitler and Kim Jong Un wants to do good for some people (despite harming others in the process). What's in it for Unalag? Money? Be a king? Have harem? Looks like he lost all that by being giant.

But let's put that aside for a while.

Unalag and Vaatu is winning. Huray.... I always like it when the bad guys win.

Then suddenly Korra can spawn some megaloman. And then there is this little kid that does some magic can cast light or whatever.

And then? Vaatu death? That's it? No physical blow. No punch. He's death because Raava is extracted from it? Not making any sense to me. I know it's fiction. But looks like we have some spiritual mambo jambo and then poof, Korra win.

What actually happened?

Comment: Mecha Streisand pre-dates the Legend of Korra by over a decade, so it's certainly not a parody of something that did not exist yet.

Comment: It's a parody of all movies with this kind of gender. I am so evil my life goal is to be a giant and bring darkness

Comment: Maybe korra is a parody of Mecha Streisand?

Answer (score 4):

**It is a bit complicated.**

**Summary:** Korra made an amplified spiritual projection to fight UnaVaatu, however she lost. Then, spiritual projection of Jinora awakened Raava inside the Vaatu so Korra became connected with Raava again. After that, she spirit bended UnaVaatu.

> *Korra:* Raava is gone. I am not connected to her spirit anymore.
>
> *Tenzin:* I am not talking about Raava. Raava is not who you are.....The most powerful thing about you is not the spirit of Raava, but your own inner spirit. You have always been strong, unyielding and fearless.

Here, we establish that Korra is strong without Raava as well. Inner spirit plays crucial role in Korra's last defence against Unalaq.

> *Tenzin:* You have to help them Korra.
>
> *Korra:* How? They're half way around the world.
>
> *Tenzin:* Do as the ancients did. Connect to the cosmic energy of the universe. Don't bend the elements **but bend the energy within yourself.**

So, Korra bent the energy within herself to amplify her spiritual projection.

> *Raava:* He cannot destroy light anymore than I can destroy darkness. One cannot exist without the other. Even if I were to defeat Vaatu in this encounter, darkness would grow inside me until he emerges again. The same will hold true if Vaatu defeats me.
>
> *Wan:* That doesn't sound so bad. Even if Vaatu wins, you'll still come back.
>
> *Raava:* Yes, but you will probably not survive to see it.

This quote, and many other quotes in the same season suggest that Raava is not dead but alive within Vaatu. Naturally, it would reemerge after some time but it would take more than the span of a human life. I guess it is implied that darkness will rule the world until the next harmonic convergence, which is an event that happens every 10.000 years.

Jinora comes into play here. She accelerates Raava's emergence. And Korra pulls Raava out of Vaatu and then performs spirit bending on UnaVaatu. Spirit bending balances a spirit's negative and positive energy. This part is not very well established within the series, but Vaatu is no longer a prisoner in the Tree of Time at the end of the episode. Korra says something that gives a hint:

> *Korra:* I'm sorry about your father. But he was already fused with Vaatu. I couldn't save him.

So, at the end of spirit bending, Korra might have killed Vaatu. If she did, he will reemerge after some time, inside Raava.

Comment: So Korra killed Unavaatu? By taking Raava out of Unavaatu that causes mortal wound against the giant?

Comment: @user4951 No, bt spirit bending. Vaatu became balanced and he/she went to his/her way but Unalaq couldn't because of his mortal body.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier in the show Raava explains that neither the light nor the darkness can be destroyed, only contained. After each of their fights, either Raava or Vatu are defeated and the other reigns over the world, spreading peace and order (Raava) or chaos and destruction (Vatu). But over time, the defeated spirit regrows inside the reigning victor until it fights free and they begin the cycle again.

What Korra and her friends were able to do is pull Raava free much faster than usual and rejoin the fight, defeating the dark Avatar after he thought he's already won and let his guard down.

Earlier episodes help build a framework within the world that allow this fight to make sense, based on how the cycles develop and what the different characters are capable of.

Comment: Okay vaatu defeat Raava? No problem. Korra pulled out Vaatu from Unavaatu? Arghh...... The dark avatar is defeated